# Git Flow Versioning with Maven

Tags: git, maven, git-flow

We are developing a multi-module maven project and have just switched over to the git-flow model. We have a problem when it comes to versioning and merges. We recently started our release/1.10 branch and our develop branch has moved on to 1.11-SNAPSHOT. However, when we go to make merges from release/1.10 back to develop, it overwrites the version number in develop. Is there a best practice for dealing with this? I did write a bump_version.sh script but it still seems cumbersome to have to keep pushing it back and forth.

Comment: "it overwrites the version number in develop" What do you mean by this? Overwrites the version number where?

Comment: The pom for develop contains `<version>1.11-SNAPSHOT</version>` and release/1.10 contains `<version>1.10</version>`. When the release branch is merged back onto develop, develop now reads `<version>1.10</version>` which is incorrect.

Comment: The version *should've* come up as a merge conflict, which you would resolve by choosing the `1.11-SNAPSHOT` line.  Since it didn't, this suggests that you had changed the version on `develop` to `1.11-SNAPSHOT` already on the commit where the release branch was created, allowing git to see the release branch's change of the version as "newer".  Double-check if this is the case; if so, that's the issue. The best practice would be to create the release branch from a `develop` commit prior to the version number change.

Comment: Thanks, that may be the case, we had a bunch of project structure changes. The next question is how to deal with potential conflicts in 16 pom files.